# What is the connection pool jar does Wildfly 9 use?

Tags: java, wildfly, connection-pooling

There are many database connection pool implementation available for java, for example; commons-dbcp , commons-dbcp2 ( newer version) , Hikari cp , tomcat jdbc connection pool and c3p0. Wildfly lets the application to be configured the connection pool in the datasource ( in the standalone*.xml ) files. 
But wondering does Wildfly uses any of the connection pool implementations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildfly uses [iron jacamar](http://www.ironjacamar.org/news/2015/04/14/IronJacamar124FinalReleased.html) version 1.2.4 which is an implementation of the [Java EE JCA specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=322). 
All binaries are located in the module /org/jboss/ironjacamar.
JCA is used to connect different kind of enterprise system in your application server (Message Broker, SAP, etc..) not only RDB.